# How to make a grid in java using only for loops, if else statements and System.out.println

Tags: java

Please help, I have to make a 20 x 20 grid of asterisks with a  jack-o'-lantern face for my programming class. I can't seem to get it into a grid. It prints out in a long vertical line, with parts of the face together randomly. This is what I have so far:

```
public class DottinoN_ExtraCredit
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    int row, col;
    for(row = 0; row < 20; row++)
    {
      for(col = 0; col < 20; col++)
      {
        if((row == 2) && (col == 2) ||(row == 2) && (col == 3) || (row == 2) && (col == 4) || (row == 3) && (col == 2)
             || (row == 3) && (col == 4) || (row == 4) && (col == 2) ||(row == 4) && (col == 3) || (row == 4) && (col == 4)
             || (row == 2) && (col == 15) ||(row == 2) && (col ==16) || (row == 2) && (col == 17) 
             || (row == 3) && (col == 15) || (row == 3) && (col == 17) 
             || (row == 4) && (col == 15) ||(row == 4) && (col == 16) || (row == 4) && (col == 17))
        {
          System.out.print("O");
        }
        else
        {
          if((row == 7) && (col == 9) || (row == 7) && (col == 10) || (row == 8) && (col == 8) || (row == 8) 
               && (col == 9) || (row == 8) && (col == 10) || (row == 8) && (col == 11)) 
          {
            System.out.print("X");
          }
          else
          {
            if((row == 13) && (col == 5) || (row == 13) && (col == 6) || (row == 13) && (col == 7) || 
               (row == 13) && (col == 8) || (row == 13) && (col == 9) || (row == 13) && (col == 10) || 
               (row == 13) && (col == 11) || (row == 13) && (col == 12) || (row == 13) && (col == 13) || 
               (row == 13) && (col == 14) || (row == 14) && (col == 5) || (row == 14) && (col == 6) || 
               (row == 14) && (col == 7) || (row == 14) && (col == 8) || (row == 14) && (col == 9) || 
               (row == 14) && (col == 10) || (row == 14) && (col == 11) || (row == 14) && (col == 12) || 
               (row == 14) && (col == 13) || (row == 14) && (col == 14))
            {
              System.out.println("|");
            }
            else
            {
              System.out.print("*");
          }
          }
        }
        System.out.println("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why go such a tedious task , homework ??

Comment: Generally, homework (and extra credit) are frowned upon unless the problem is extremely specific and well-thought-out,

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `System.out.println("|");` to `System.out.print("|");` - you really don't want that newline in there.

Comment: Thank you, that made a huge difference

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated and uncomfortable?

```
public void printFigure() {

String[] l = new String[20];
int p = 0;
//       01234567890123456789
l[p++]= "XOOOO----OOOOOOOOOX";
l[p++]= "XOOO(....)OOOOOOOOX";
l[p++]= "XOOOO-----OOOOOOOOX";
l[p++]= "XOOOOXXXOOOOOOOOOOX";
// Add the remaining lines 
 ---
for (int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(l[i];
}
}
```

But hopefully an array is allowed, otherwise this programming task makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The very last `System.out.println("");` executes at the end of the column for. Basically you are putting every single column in a new line. That's why you get a huge vertical line.